# Editable screenshot.png in a custom theme developed

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

is it possible to make the screenshot.png editable via theme options or customizer?

What I'm trying to achieve here is to allow my client the ability to change the theme screenshot image when they viewed the appearance->themes.

I look over for wp_upload_dir but it seems not the right thing to do as it creates an upload folder.

Does anyone can shed lights on this? Thanks

Comment: IMHO, I would just add the required screenshot in the theme folder. I really do not see any use in constantly changing your theme's screenshot pic on the site. I do not think there is any valid reason to do this on a production site.

Comment: Like @PieterGoosen said: it's not really common to do this. However if you really want to do it you can create a custom `meta_box` and insert an upload field where the location is you theme folder. It must overwrite the current image and it's name.